# Paypal one user pay to protal and portal pay to another user

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I need to make portal that able to get money from one user and pay another user, when fill some conditions. User order some item, he must pay a portal that price, then when user pay portal, portal get some percent and other pay to user which is item which first user ordered, it's a two different transactions.

I think that paypal is good for that but I do not know how to do that.

I start to implement portal in laravel framework. Has anybody any idea how to I implement something like that.

Comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) : Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it

Comment: It's not a homework. I only search a solution how to solve my personal problem on my project.

Comment: I haven't down voted your question. Even if it is not a homework, your question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by two way (as per my knowledge)

1) Using Paypal Adaptive payments

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

2) First accept payments from first user(Buyer) then after keeping your percentage pay to second user (seller) by paypal transaction using email address or using any offline mode.

Comment: TNX. I only need a direction where to start and how  to start with that. I will tray both and than decide which one to get. Thank you @ahaykumartak